# SD card not mounting with: mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

Tags: usb, mount, sd-card

I have card Sandisk SDXC 128 GB EXTREME PRO 95MB/s C10 V30 UHS-I U3.
It is working on Windows/Mac and my Fujifilm camera.

On my laptop (tested also on other laptops with Ubuntu) I got error:

```
mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

Details:
Dell Precision 5520, lsusb do not list this card. Card not visible in drives. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                                                                                             
Linux dell-5520 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Card formatted with exfat, but I have drivers for this filesystem installed.

Comment: I confirm the same issue on Linux Debian 10 with a brand new Sandisk SDXC Extreme Pro 128GB 170MB/S. Just tested and on Windows, but replies with "error -110" on Linux 4.19.0-4-amd64 on a Lenovo Thinkpad.

Comment: Same problem here. I have a handful of brand new "SanDisk Ultra Plus" and "SanDisk Extreme Plus"; the Ultra work perfectly fine, but the Extreme do not work on Linux. The block devices don't appear, and I get the same message, `mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card`. The cards work fine in cameras, BlackMagic recorders, and on the same machine using Windows; but they don't work on any on my Linux machines. I believe the Linux MMC driver is supposed to configure the port in a particular way (different voltage? Frequency?) but fails to do so; but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [discussion at kernel.org](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11088719/) about this topic. 
The reason has to do with the module rtsx_pci and the low voltage interface (LVI).

There is a patch available (2019-08-27, at the bottom), to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

A patch in regard to this issue should be available now.

[Bug 201447 - SDXC scandisk Extreme UHS-I card not recognized on DELL XPS 15-9550 laptop](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201447) :

> Philip Langdale 2019-09-16 15:38:34 UTC
>
> The patch was merged into 5.3 and all the active
>    stable branches, so you can get it right now.